# Dynamically populate <td> from return of a function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically update the contents of  cells but only if data for those cells exists in the database.

What I have tried is to add a call to the `addDataIfPres` function, from the appropriate  each time it is dynamically generated, in the hope that it would be populated with the returning data from the function: either some data if it exists for that student, or 'blank' if it does not.

But, this is not working. How can I call the `addDataIfPres` function, each time an HTML cell is created, and populate it with the returning value?

```
function makeEditTableHTML(studentArray, groupID) { 
    return populateDB(groupID, function(data) {
        // Data from AJAX POST
        console.log(data);
        
        function addDataIfPres(col, student, data) {
            for(var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if ((student == data[j][0]) && (col == 1)) {
                    res = data[j][1];
                }
                else {
                    res = "";
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
        
        var result = "<table id='dataEditTableid' class='stripe' border=1><thead><tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Student Email</b></td><td><b>Group ID</b></td><td><b>Target</b></td><td><b>SEN</b></td><td><b>Disadvantaged</b></td></tr></thead>";
        result += "<tbody>";
        
        for(var i=0; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
            result += "<tr>";
            result += "<td>"+studentArray[i][1]+"</td>";
            result += "<td>"+studentArray[i][0]+"</td>";
            result += "<td>"+groupID+"</td>";
            result += "<td id=" + studentArray[i][1] + " contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(1, this.id, this.innerHTML, "+groupID+")'>+ addDataIfPres(1, this.id, data) +</td>";
            result += "<td id=" + studentArray[i][1] + " contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(2, this.id, this.innerHTML, "+groupID+")'></td>";
            result += "<td id=" + studentArray[i][1] + " contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(3, this.id, this.innerHTML, "+groupID+")'></td>";
            result += "</tr>";
        }
        
        result += "</tbody></table>";
        
        dataTable.innerHTML = result;
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataEditTableid').DataTable({                                                           
            });
        });
        
        return result;
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: No, it is displaying the function call text but not the returning value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually call the function because the code is still part of the string (missing quotation marks to denote the end of the string).

Try this:

```
result += "<td id=" + studentArray[i][1] + " contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(1, this.id, this.innerHTML, "+groupID+")'>" + addDataIfPres(1, this.id, data) + "</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Whilst you are there, `this.id`, when passed into the function, is showing up as undefined. But it works fine when passed into the onBlue function call. Any ideas why?

Comment: You have to pass in `studentArray[i][1]` explicitly instead of `this.id`. This part of the code has nothing to do with the actual DOM-Element so you cannot access `this` (meaning the current td-element). `this` in this case refers to the global `window` object.